# Movie where girl who lives with father's talking head and repairs androids, mistakes protagonist for android

Tags: story-identification, movie

Two scenes from an unidentified sci-fi movie have started to pop into my head while browsing scifi.stackexchange:

**Scene #1:** A girl is talking with her father. They might be on a space station but not for sure. He is seen as a head atop a large dark box, reminiscent of someone standing inside an iron lung, but he could also be a head on top of a machine.

**Scene #2:** The girl is tending to a number of life-like robots/androids, some partly disassembled. Someone is singing. This appears to be her job. What is presumably the protagonist of the movie appears along the androids and is startled when the girl thinks he's an android in for service and tries to inspect/unscrew/dismantle him. She apologizes with a reference to 'not seeing many people here, except her father'. I believe the protagonist may have been fleeing or hiding up until then.

It was a color movie, seen on TV no earlier than 1986, but could have been made anytime from the early Seventies onward. I'm guessing the movie had a tame rating as I was a kid at the time and must have seen it on daytime TV. The kind that might have made good MST3K material.

Comment: There is a Tom Baker Dr Who arc in which the companion-of-the-moment is mistaken for an android and sent for maintenance, but it doesn't seem to match the rest of the description. The setting was psuedo-medieval.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems, that this movie is: [Battle beyond the Stars (1980)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080421/).
And this is the screenshot from it (girl's father, I suppose):

[image]

And here You can actually watch it: [Battle beyond the Stars (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFA6FnOqfwI&feature=player_detailpage#t=1146)

Comment: There it is! :-D The android workshop scene is much as I remember it, though "the head of the family" is a lot less intimidating than I remember it :-P